# Reading signals in a car 9-14.5v and translating to arduino HIGH / LOW

Tags: arduino, voltage, 12v

I have a project that requires me to trigger certain events in an Arduino based on certain electronic devices in the car being switched on and off. I essentially need to read a 12v HIGH state in the car as a 5v high state via an Arduino, but as the cars voltage will fluctuate between 11 & 14.5 v and suffer from transient spikes, I would like to do this as simply and safely as possible.

Currently, my thoughts are a voltage divider with some form of transient spike protection (zener diode?), but I am open to better suggestions!

I need to read 3 separate 12v HIGH events (main beam on, lights on, indicators on) to effect changes in intensity on a set of high brightness DRLs.

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll need quite good transient supression and regulation for the power supply to the Arduino, too.

Comment: Yes, I am using a pre-built one from ebay (lazy I know but I needed a decent supply and they were cheap. It steps the car down to 9.5v for the LED rings I am using then I step down to 5 with a normal 5v reg. Its a DC-DC LM2596 Converter Buck Adjustable Step Down Regulator Power Module 1.2 -35V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider opto-couplers. That would give you very good trasient protection.

Comment: I had come to a similar conclusion. I have ordered some FOD852 Darlington Optocoupler's which should do the job nicely. Never used them before but look straight forward.